# How to setup named-Virtual hosts in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I would like to setup the following, as soon as I enter MySite.com in my local browser, I would like to be pointed at 127.0.0.1:8000.

I have done some research and it seems with nginx I could setup a reverse proxy on port 80 that will redirect traffic to Django port 8000.

I have been googeling for some time and did these steps.:

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

In there I edited the config file like this:

```
server {

        listen       80;
        server_name  MySite.com;

        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {

        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

        }
}
```

But this still doesn't work. What am I missing please?

**UPDATE**

Alright this is the latest version, which still doesn't work, it simply goes to the real MySite.com on Internet.

server {

```
    listen       80;
    server_name  MySite.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {

            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
            proxy_redirect     http://MySite.com:8000/ /;

            proxy_set_header   Host             $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

            client_max_body_size       10m;
            client_body_buffer_size    128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout      90;
            proxy_send_timeout         90;
            proxy_read_timeout         90;

            proxy_buffer_size          4k;
            proxy_buffers              4 32k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

            }
```

Comment: Could you please add more details about how it's `doesn't work`. What happend exacly? nginx fails to start? browsers gets redirected?

Comment: I type in MySite.com and actually get to http://mySite.com instead of getting to 127.0.0.1:8000.  (I have no apache running locally)

Comment: @Kave , were you able to fix this issue? I see that in comments mysite.com was still pointing to real internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are telling nginx to listen on port 80... I'm guessing apache is port 80. Your setup should be along these lines:

```
  server {
      listen 127.0.0.1:8000; # Real IP here
      server_name mysite.com;     # "_" is for handle all hosts that are not described by server_name
      charset off;
      access_log  /var/log/nginx_host_general.access.log  main;
      location / {   
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;    # Real IP here
        client_max_body_size       16m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;
      }
```

You are telling nginx to listen on port 8000, then do a proxy_pass to 127.0.0.1. You could define :80 here, but since http is port 80 by default you do not need to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  On port 8000 a Django server is running, hence this wouldn't work. MySite.com should point to the Django server.

Comment: Oh. your config should work then. What happens when you access the site? Does it load? I think it might be down to the option `proxy_redirect     off;`, it should be `proxy_redirect http://mysite.com:8000/ / ` .

Also try adding `$server_port` to the header.. like so `proxy_set_header   Host             $host:$server_port;`

Comment: I have applied your suggestions and edited my question. What do you think?

Comment: you say it just goes to the site on the internet.. Try changing `proxy_redirect default` or if that fails then proxy_redirect go to 127.0.0.1:8000, so it should be `proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8000/ /`

Comment: I have tried both. It still goes to Internet :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3735/discussion-between-sc0rian-and-kave)

Comment: Just for the records, the suggested the solution by Sc0rian, which I have reflected in my Update section works fine. But its imperative to have also the entry 127.0.0.1 MySite.com in /etc/hosts or it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you edit your `/etc/hosts` file so it doesn't try and translate www.mysite.com through external DNS.  It should be an entry like this:

```
your_IP www.mysite.com   #your_IP is your actual IP address
```